# NullReferenceException and don't know how to fix it

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, instantiation

Okay, I am making a simple game mechanic where you are a ball rolling along a small panel. On the edge of the panel are 8 child objects. 4 of them are triggers on the edges of the panel, and 4 of them are empty game objects 1 unit away from each edge of the panel for the location of the next panel prefab to spawn at. The ball has a trigger on it that detects the location of the empty game objects to tell the panel prefab where to spawn. When the ball enters a specific trigger frm the panel the ball is suppose to instantiate a panel prefab on the location that I assign based on the trigger the ball enters. Here is my code:

```
public GameObject panelPrefab; 

Transform frontSpawn; 
Transform backSpawn;
Transform leftSpawn; 
Transform rightSpawn;

private bool allowSpawn; 

void Awake()
{
    allowSpawn = true; 
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider spawn)
{
    if (spawn.gameObject.tag == "FrontSpawn")
    {
        frontSpawn = spawn.transform; 
    }
    else if (spawn.gameObject.tag == "BackSpawn")
    {
        backSpawn = spawn.transform; 
    }
    else if (spawn.gameObject.tag == "LeftSpawn") 
    {
        leftSpawn = spawn.transform; 
    }
    else if (spawn.gameObject.tag == "RightSpawn") 
    {
        rightSpawn = spawn.transform;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Front" && allowSpawn == true) 
    {
        Instantiate (panelPrefab, frontSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        allowSpawn = false; 
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Back" && allowSpawn == true) 
    {
        Instantiate (panelPrefab, backSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 
        allowSpawn = false;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Left" && allowSpawn == true) 
    {
        Instantiate (panelPrefab, leftSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 
        allowSpawn = false;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Right" && allowSpawn == true) 
    {
        Instantiate (panelPrefab, rightSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 
        allowSpawn = false;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) 
{
    allowSpawn = true;
}
```

My issue is on each of the Instantiate calls, I am getting a NullReferenceException. I have the panelPrefab assigned in the unity editor, and I don't know what could be causing this! If anyone can help me here it would be GREATLY appreciated... So thank you in advance!

Comment: Happened to me once. First try to spawn.gameObject.transform; instead of spawn.transform; If it didn't solve, silly thing is you need to restart Unity/PC/Mac etc. Hope it will be solved.

Comment: certainly your ide should say which line gives that error. please tell the line for easier and exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

`OnTriggerEnter` is called before `OnTriggerStay`. The error is not due to the `panelPrefab` object. It might happen that your `rightSpawn`, `leftSpawn` etc. objects are null and hence cannot access the transform property of a null object.

Before instantiating verify if `rightSpawn` etc. is null or not and then access it's position.

Comment: I didn't even think about the placement of the OnTriggers... But yes, the rightSpawn, leftSpawn etc are null and I don't know what to do about it, so I'm looking for a new method. But thanks anyway!